# Rails deploying with docker-compose, assets doesn't working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, assets, unicorn, precompile

This is an extremely helpful article that I followed:

[Docker for an Existing Rails Application](http://chrisstump.online/2016/02/20/docker-existing-rails-application/)

I was stuck on the problem. The application can run with no error, the index page can be see from the web surf. But the index page looks wired, looks like the scss doesn't working and the image doesn't appear.

From the Chrome Console, I got this:

[image]

I did a lot search and found it maybe the assets:premcompile. I changed the *docker-compose.yml* , run `docker-compose run app rake db: assets:precompile`, even I copied the `public/assets/*` to the container, but no luck.

Host Computer: CentOS 7

**Any idea is great. Thanks in advance.**

#### docker-compose.yml

```
1 app:
2     build: .
3
4     env_file: .env.production
5
6     environment:
7         RAILS_ENV: $RAILS_ENV
8
9     links:
10         - db
11

14     expose:
15         - "3000"
16
17 db:
18     image: postgres:9.4.5
19
20     volumes:
21         - eshop-postgres:/var/lib/postgresql/data
22
23 web:
24     build: .
25
26     dockerfile: config/containers/Dockerfile-nginx
27
28     volumes:
29         - ./public:/var/www/eshop/public
30
31     links:
32         - app
33     ports:
34         - "80:80"
```

#### Dockerfile

```
      2 FROM ruby:2.3.3-slim
     12 RUN apt-get update -qq && apt-get install -y build-essential libpq-dev postgresql-client libsqlite3-dev nodejs vim
     15 ENV RAILS_ROOT /var/www/myapp
     18 RUN mkdir -p $RAILS_ROOT/tmp/pids
     19
     21 WORKDIR $RAILS_ROOT
     22
     26 COPY Gemfile Gemfile
     27
     28 COPY Gemfile.lock Gemfile.lock
     29
     31 RUN gem install bundler
     32
     34 RUN bundle install
     35
     37 COPY . .
     38

     39 - RUN RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile --trace~
     40 - RUN bundle exec rake assets:precompile --trace~

     40 + RUN bundle exec rake RAILS_ENV=$RAILS_ENV DATABASE_URL=postgresql://$POSTGRES_USER:$POSTGRES_PASSWORD@127.0.0.1/$POSTGRES_PRODUCTION_DB assets:precompile
     41 + VOLUMES ["$RAILS_ROOT/public"]

     46 + CMD [ "config/containers/app_cmd.sh" ]
```

#### config/container/Docker-nginx

```
      2 FROM nginx

     12 RUN apt-get update -qq && apt-get -y install apache2-utils vim

     15 ENV RAILS_ROOT /var/www/myapp

     18 WORKDIR $RAILS_ROOT

     21 RUN mkdir log

     25 COPY public public/

     28 COPY config/containers/nginx.conf /tmp/myapp.nginx

     32 RUN envsubst '$RAILS_ROOT' < /tmp/myappv.nginx > /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf

     35 CMD [ "nginx", "-g", "daemon off;" ]
```

### UPDATED:

I made some updates according to @bkunzi01 advices. But no luck.

#### Dockerfile

```
 40 RUN bundle exec rake RAILS_ENV=$RAILS_ENV DATABASE_URL=postgresql://$POSTGRES_USER:$POSTGRES_PASSWORD@127.0.0.1/$POSTGRES_PRODUCTION_DB assets:precompile
 41 VOLUME ["$RAILS_ROOT/public"] 

 46 CMD [ "config/containers/app_cmd.sh" ]
```

#### .env.production

```
# *.env.production*    

RAILS_ENV=production
RAILS_ROOT=/var/www/eshop
SECRET_KEY_BASE=the_long_code
POSTGRES_PRODUCTION_DB=production_db
POSTGRES_USER=postgres
POSTGRES_PASSWORD=keep_secret_ps
```

There is another [warn] in the log of `docker-compose`:

```
web_1  | 2017/03/02 05:45:14 [warn] 1#1: server name "/var/www/eshop/public" has suspicious symbols in /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf:16
web_1  | nginx: [warn] server name "/var/www/eshop/public" has suspicious symbols in /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf:16
```

Comment: have the same problem with assets... looks like these is no normal tutorial for using docker-compose with nginx, rails and database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most people have this error because they're missing node.js however you have that so I think the next likely candidate is to add a volume directive and also consider changing your precompiling command on line 39 of the dockerfile to:

```
RUN bundle exec rake RAILS_ENV=production DATABASE_URL=postgresql://user:pass@127.0.0.1/dbname SECRET_TOKEN=makeupasecret assets:precompile

VOLUME ["$RAILS_ROOT/public"]
```

Adding this volume directive here will expose your assets to nginx by keeping the precompiled assets in a volume.

Also, you can makeup anything you want for the secret_token and the database info.
The reason is that Rails will freak out when the secret token and user aren't supplied but you can totally make them up because Rails doesn't check them here lol...

Plus make sure to remove that second precompile:assets command since it's not needed.

Note:  I'd also add at the end of the Dockerfile a line to trigger running unicorn or whatever other appserver you're going to run rails on behind nginx.

Ex.  `CMD bundle exec unicorn -c config/unicorn.rb`

Comment: I made some updates above. Is it must be set the  `SECRET_TOKEN` after I have a `SECRET_KEY_BASE`?  I have no idea about this. If it must be, how can I get the `SECRET_TOKEN` value? @bkunzi01 Thank you again.

Comment: The volume `VOLUME ["$RAILS_ROOT/public"]` now is working. I can create a new file, and saw it in the container. But the assets not working.

Comment: That means Nginx doesn't know where to serve them from.  I'm at work but can maybe help out when I get back tonight if you're still stuck!

Comment: You're so kind. I really need your help. Of course, I'll try my best to try solve it, but I don't think I can do it by myself.

Answer (score 4):

I was having the exactly same issue. Turns out that the real reason was that `config.public_file_server.enabled` was not set in my `config/environments/production.rb`.

To solve this, I simply added an environment variable to my `docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: '2'
services:
  app:
    ...
    environment:
      - RAILS_SERVE_STATIC_FILES=true
```

I'm using Rails 5.0.1.

Hope this helps.

Comment: You really do not want to let your Ruby stack handle serving static files in production. This is a hack at best.

Comment: This works, asset digests are still used. I dont see the issue. Spend hours figuring this out

Comment: @Ariejan could you expand on that? what would be the problem of ruby serving static files?

Answer (score 0):

I came across this post as I had the same problem. I've since pretty much resolved it by stripping down my container. I consulted the Docker docs for Rails: https://docs.docker.com/compose/rails/ and adjusted my Dockerfile and docker-compose.yml file accordingly.

I went ahead and nixed nginx for now, since I'm a Docker n00b and just want my thing to work first.

Here is my **Dockerfile**

```
# Base image:
FROM ruby:2.3.1

# Install dependencies
RUN apt-get update -qq && apt-get install -y build-essential libpq-dev postgresql-client nodejs

# Set an environment variable where the Rails app is installed to inside of Docker image:
ENV RAILS_ROOT /Users/jessecalton/WatchNext
RUN mkdir -p $RAILS_ROOT/tmp/pids

# Set working directory, where the commands will be ran:
WORKDIR $RAILS_ROOT



# Gems:
ADD Gemfile* $RAILS_ROOT

RUN gem install bundler
RUN bundle install

# Copy the main application.
COPY . $RAILS_ROOT
```

And my **docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '3'
services:
  # service configuration for our dockerized Rails app
  app:
    # use the Dockerfile next to this file
    build: .



    # sources environment variable configuration for our app
    env_file: .env

    # rely on the RAILS_ENV value of the host machine
    environment:
      RAILS_ENV: $RAILS_ENV


    # makes the app container aware of the DB container
    links:
      - db

    # expose the port we configured Unicorn to bind to
    expose:
      - "3000"

  # service configuration for our database
  db:

    # use the preferred version of the official Postgres image
    # see https://hub.docker.com/_/postgres/
    image: postgres:latest

  # service configuration for our web server
  web:

    # set the build context to the root of the Rails app
    build: .
    command: bundle exec rails s -p 3000 -b '0.0.0.0'

    volumes:
      - /Users/jessecalton/WatchNext/

    # makes the web container aware of the app container
    links:
      - app

    # expose the port we configured Nginx to bind to
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    depends_on:
      - db
```

I followed the other configuration instructions from the https://docs.docker.com/compose/rails/ site, and after creating and migrating my database, got everything to work.

**Full disclosure:** I still have to find a way to close and re-open the Puma server without dropping the container and thus dropping the database. In other words, if you Ctrl+C to close the server and then do `docker-compose up` again, Puma will still be running in the background and your app will exit, citing "a server is already running."

Just wanted to pass this info along as your same exact issue was giving me troubles all day.